# C# httpWebRespond содержит не полные ссылки

Tags: c#

Получаю страницу с помощью метода httpWebRespond просматриваю полученный текст деббагером и вижу что ссылки не полные, т.е. если код страницы смотрю в firefox все ссылки выглядят так <a href = "http:\www.server.ru\mainpage.asp"></a>, но после получения html страницы методом GetResponseStream() вижу следующее <a href = "mainpage.asp"></a>. Как все-таки получать в ответе полные ссылки?

Comment: Вы уверены, что firefox показал вам в точности то, что пришло от сервера? Давать полный URL на внутренние ссылки — не самая хорошая идея.

Comment: Я разобрался, firefox при видимо преобразует код страницы и на выходе добавляет помимо абсолютных урл еще и различные теги. Решил так при парсинге страницы полученные ссылки извлекаю и преобразую так new Uri(server_url, extracted_link)

Comment: @fox06: Наверное, вместо `server_url` надо `current_page_url`?